# Filling an array with strings from a text file, every element of the array is the same

Tags: arrays, c, fgets

I am trying to read in a text file, and then line by line add the strings into an array.

```c
int main() {

    // open text file
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("read1.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Can't open file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // run through the text file and count how many lines there are 
    int size = 0;
    while (fgets(line, 255, fp) != NULL) {
        size++;
    }

    // reset the file pointer
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    // initialise an array to hold each line
    char *linesArr[size];
    
    // run through file again filling array with the lines
    int index = 0;
    while (index < size) {
        fgets(line, 255, fp);
        linesArr[index] = line;
        printf("%s", line);
        index++;
    }

    printf("%s\n", linesArr[0]);
    printf("%s\n", linesArr[1]);
    printf("%s\n", linesArr[2]);

}
```

An example file could look like

```
David
James
Alice
Bob
```

And the output of the executable would be

```
David
James
Alice
BobBob
Bob
Bob
```

It appears that although setting each entry of the array to `line`, which a variable that I am checking the value of and seeing that it has the correct name at each stage. By the end of the program, every entry in the array is the same.

Comment: what is `line` , is it a `char line[]`?, if so replace this line `linesArr[index] = line;` with `strcpy(linesArr[index] ,line)` after allocating memory for `linesArr[index]` or use `linesArr` as `char linesArr[size][size]` then use `strcpy`

Comment: `linesArr[index] = line;` will always assigns the address of `line` to all values of `linesArr`, that is why you see all entries are same.

Comment: Understand `char *linesArr[size];` declares `size` number of *Uninitialized* pointers that point to no valid storage. When you assign `linesArr[index] = line;` you assign a pointer to `line` (due to array/pointer conversion [6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)) so that every element holds the address of the array -- resulting in all elements of `linesArr` pointing to whatever `line` held last. `linesArr[index] = strdup(line);` will allocate storage and copy `line` to that storage for you. (POSIX)